# Read a file name by date on javascript

Tags: javascript, amcharts, amcharts4

i'm trying to read a file by date with JS
i tried to replace the varable TimeNow without success.
when fo example i make fixed filename it works fine, but replacing the filename with a variable 'TimeNow' it doesnt work.

```js
var prex = document.querySelector('pre');

var DateNow = new Date();
DateNow.setHours(DateNow.getHours()-1);

var TimeNow=DateNow.getFullYear() + "" + (DateNow.getMonth()+1) + "" + DateNow.getDate();
loadCSV("counters_test_directory_${TimeNow}.log");

prex.innerHTML += '\n\n';
prex.innerHTML += TimeNow;
```

```html
<pre>
</pre>
```

Comment: You need to use the backticks, not double quotes for variable interpolation in strings.

Comment: you can't load a file from the browser like that. you have to ask the user to select the file.

Comment: Where is `loadCSV` coming from and are you running this in node or browser? To me it looks like you may be using a node package `loadCSV` in browser land... and also the syntax error you got that @Phix pointed out.

Comment: i tried the backticks and doesn't work $`TimeNow` and `$TimeNow``

Comment: You can use const time = instanceOfFile.lastModified;

Comment: No, I mean `\`counters_test_directory_${TimeNow}.log\``

Comment: it doesnt work @Phix , for info im using AMchart site scripts

Comment: See https://jsfiddle.net/op0bmhk6/, other than "it doesn't work" I'm stumped on how to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
loadCSV(`counters_test_directory_${TimeNow}.log`);
```

```js
var prex = document.querySelector('pre');

var DateNow = new Date();
DateNow.setHours(DateNow.getHours()-1);

var TimeNow=DateNow.getFullYear() + "" + (DateNow.getMonth()+1) + "" + DateNow.getDate();
alert(`counters_test_directory_${TimeNow}.log`);
// The source of this function is NOT given.
//loadCSV(`counters_test_directory_${TimeNow}.log`);

prex.innerHTML += '\n\n';
prex.innerHTML += TimeNow;
```

```html
<pre>
</pre>
```

Comment: like that loadCSV("counters_test_directory_20200626.log"); it works fine but with variable it's not working

Comment: You are using double quotation mark -> ". JS template strings are using backtick. Please  take a closer look at the fixed code.

Comment: it works now, when i used the Alert i detect that date format was not correct, thank you verry much